# Printing and updating all the documents in MongoDB using Node.js driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm writing a script that should get the number of the documents in the collection and  then print them all, and then update each of them, the thing is that i'm getting an error while running it: MongoError: Connection Closed by application.
Here is my code i've tried to put the db.close() in several places it doesn't helped.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require ('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var dbName = "yahooStocks";
var port = "27017";
var requiredCollection = "stocks"
var host = "localhost";


MongoClient.connect("mongodb://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbName, function (error, db){

        if(error) throw error;
        console.log ("Connected to: " + "mongodb://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbName);
    function update () {

        db.collection(requiredCollection).count({}, function (error, numOfDocs) {
            if(error) throw error;
            console.log("the number of docs is : " , numOfDocs);

            for (i=1; i<10; i++) {
                var findOneQuery = {'_id' : i};
                db.collection(requiredCollection).findOne(findOneQuery, function (error, doc) {
                    if(error) throw error;

                    console.log(doc._id + ". Doc - > " , doc);

                }); // end of findOne

                //db.close();
            }

             db.close();
        }); // end of count




    }
update();
// db.close();
 }); // end of connection to MongoClien
```

Comment: I think the problem is the async nature of find and findOne. The db.close() is called while the findOne in the inner loop is still executed. Maybe you can introduce a callback that closes the connection gracefully.

Comment: Can you show me some example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the **count**, how about simply countdown in your *callback* of **findOne**. Hence you could know when are those operations in the loops all completed, and safely call `db.close()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure to run those queries in asynchronous manner. Best way to do it is to use async library. (this example is using mongoose)

Using async library: https://github.com/caolan/async

```
var queries = [];

for (i=1; i<10; i++) {
    queries.push(db.collection(requiredCollection).findOne({'_id' : i}));
}

async.each(queries, function(query, callback) {
    query.exec(function(err, doc) {
      if (err) callback(err);

      console.log(doc._id + ". Doc - > " , doc);

      // do things here

      callback();
    });
}, function(err) {
    // when everything is complete.
});
```

Comment: Yea, I forgot you were using just MongoClient, which has different syntax than what I am doing. Make sure to checkout async lib, and the flow should be the same, but different syntax.

Comment: Where should i close the db?

Comment: Where it finishes the callback, check comment "// when everything is complete"

Comment: The thing is that the :  queries.push(db.collection(requiredCollection).findOne({'_id' : i}))
is not going to work because the function is asynchronous you wrote it in a synchronous way...
What is the function(query, callback) ?

Comment: I used a mongoose model as an example, but you can achieve similar results using the same library.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60029/discussion-between-tpae-and-user3502786).

Comment: Can you change it please to mongodb model because i wasn't able understanf how rewrite it